# ng-bootstrap offcanvas not displaying correctly

Tags: ng-bootstrap

The ng-bootstrap offcanvas seems like it's trying to work but doesn't.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eePCY.png)

As you can see, it acts like it's there and initalizes it fine, but it's not actually there. I also tried just doing the basic demo offcanvas, and if I click the backdrop then it will actually show the dismiss reason, so it seems like everything is hooking up correctly, it's just the offcanvas is hidden somehow.

I don't have any customs scss for that page that should be interfering with the offcanvas.

Dependency versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/cdk": "^13.3.2",
"@angular/cli": "^15.1.5",
"@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/localize": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
"@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
```

Currently working on a stackblitz demo to see if I can reproduce there, but it's been installing @ng-bootstrap for the past 10 minutes, so not looking good there.

Edit:
Was able to get a StackBlitz going, not able to reproduce there.
However, upon comparing the elements the visibility: visible does not show up on my list of css but does on the stackblitz. Manually adding that to the css makes it visible. Adding the same css to the .scss file for that component does not work though.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yttrbz

Edit:
I added a panel class the way the docs want you to do it:

```
const options: NgbOffcanvasOptions = {
      position: 'end',
      panelClass: 'visibility: visible',
    };
    const ref = this.offcanvasService.open(Component, options);
```

and that works. However I did notice one thing; the open animation is smooth, but the close animation is horrendously choppy. There's got to be some kind of package mismatch. Someone smarter than me might know.

Another edit 3/21/23:
I was comparing data from my local chrome devtools to the ng-bootstrap data and noticed that I have some classes missing from my source.css file, so I had to add these classes to my styles.scss file:

```
.offcanvas.showing,
.offcanvas.show:not(.hiding) {
  transform: none;
}

.offcanvas.showing,
.offcanvas.hiding,
.offcanvas.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.offcanvas.offcanvas-start {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: var(--bs-offcanvas-border-width) solid
    var(--bs-offcanvas-border-color);
  transform: translate(-100%);
}

.offcanvas.offcanvas-end {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: var(--bs-offcanvas-border-width) solid
    var(--bs-offcanvas-border-color);
  transform: translate(100%);
}
```

and removed the panelClass from NgbOffcanvasOptions and it works fine now.

[offcanvas with and without added css classes gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALoif.gif)

Not really sure why those would be missing, any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas they could just throw at me to try? The closing animation is just awful and I'd really like to get it fixed.

Comment: Don't know how they implemented it, but [this offcanvas](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/offcanvas/src) works perfectly fine, and preserves the state of components inside ([demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/overlays/offcanvas) / [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/overlay/offcanvas))